# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7167, 9557]

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, train-test-split, machine-learning-model

This is my code. I am trying to fit the model on RandomForestClassifier here:
I know that the shape of the datasets is not the problem but still it says inconsistent number of samples.

```
X_train = df_train.drop('Target',axis=1)
y_train = df_train.Target

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.25)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

rfc_model = RandomForestClassifier()

rfc_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

This is my output of shape of my X_train and y_train

```
(9557, 123)
(9557,)
```

And

```
(7167, 123) >>> X_train.shape
(2390, 123) >>> X_test.shape
(7167,)   >>> Y_train.shape, as contain only one target column
(2390,)   >>> Y_test.shape
```

Here I see that my rows of test and train datasets are same in number, so why am I getting the following error.

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [7167, 9557]

It is giving error while fitting the model.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Y_train` (with an upper-case y), you are passing `y_train` (with a lower-case y) to the fit function. As `y_train` contains the target variable from the original dataset, the fit function naturally throws an inconsistency error.

It should work okay with the correct training dataset:

```
rfc_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

I would advise adapting better naming conventions to avoid running into such issues.